# .HTACCESS Modification on Web host and Local host

Tags: regex, .htaccess

```
#Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Currently I have this piece of code, and it works when I put it on my webhost online. But the thing is, I use my localhost (own pc) for development of the website before I put it online. So when I use it on my local host, the url goes to www.localhost and this unables me to reach my own website on my local host.

Is there any way, perhaps some type of if-statement that only put that piece of code to work when I actually put it online on a webhost and not when I have it on my local host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is an if-statement in htaccess. Take a look here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#if

You can also see this:
[HTACCESS RewriteCond without messing up localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184018/htaccess-rewritecond-without-messing-up-localhost)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  \.
```

As mentioned there, this should work for localhost check.